# Obtener numeros que mas se repiten en un array - JAVA

Tags: java, array

estoy elaborando un programa en el cual quiero obtener los números que tienen mayor repetición en un Arreglo. Por ejemplo, si en mi arreglo puse los datos: 2,2,3,3,5 en mi mensaje me tendría que aparecer que los datos que tienen mayor repetición son el 2 y el 3. 
Aqui una parte del codigo en la cual valido en el arreglo el numero que se repite:

```
    if(Arreglo[i] == Arreglo[j]) 
vecesQueSeRepite++;

}

if(vecesQueSeRepite > Mrep){ 
moda = Arreglo[i]; //la moda es la posicion

Mrep = vecesQueSeRepite;
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pablo podrías agregar mas código?, que sería Mrep?, podrias especificar de manera más concreta cual sería la salida esperada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo termine resolviendo de esta manera, solo agregue otro ciclo en el cual sacara la otra posicion, lo malo es que solo funciona para 2 posiciones.

```
    for(int i=0; i<Arreglo.length; i++)
    {
        int f = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<Arreglo.length; j++)
        {
            if(Arreglo[i]==Arreglo[j])
            {
                f++;
            }   
            if(f>maxRep)
            {
                moda= Arreglo[i];
                maxRep= f;
            }   
        }
        int h = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<Arreglo.length; j++)
        {
            if(Arreglo[i]==Arreglo[j])
            {
                h++;
            }   
            if(h>=minRep)
            {
                moda2= Arreglo[i];
                minRep= h;
            }   
        }
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que te entendí, por el momento se me ocurre algo asi, no se si te sirva:
Crear una función que me retorne los números mas repetidos:

```
public static List<Integer> obtenerRepeticiones(int []numeros) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> auxNumeros = new HashMap();
        for(int num : numeros) {
            if(!auxNumeros.containsKey(num)) {
                auxNumeros.put(num, 1);
            }else {
                auxNumeros.replace(num, auxNumeros.get(num) + 1);
            }
        }
        int max = Collections.max(auxNumeros.values());
        ArrayList<Integer> numMayores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        auxNumeros.forEach((num, cant) -> {
            if(cant == max) {
                numMayores.add(num);
            }
        });
        return numMayores;
    }
```

Comment: Si utilizas un `Map`, donde la clave sea el número y el valor la cantidad de veces que se repite, la solución te quedaría mucho más elegante, simple y con un rendimiento mucho mayor. Te en cuenta que encontrar un elemento utilizando `contains()` y/o `indexOf()` requiere examinar uno a uno los elementos contenidos en tu lista. Saludos

Comment: Vale bro, voy a revisar la clase `map`, no lo conocia

Comment: Edito mi respuesta, usando la clase `Map`